# Are there any natural recursively but not primitive-recursively axiomatized theories?

Tags: lo.logic

In principle, we could have a recursively axiomatized theory for which the property numbers-an-axiom (even relative to some routine Gödel numbering scheme) is recursive but not primitive recursive. But are there any natural examples?

Of course, any such theory can be primitive-recursively reaxiomatized using Craig's trick. So we know that there can't be theories which are recursively axiomatizABLE but not primitive-recursively aziomatizABLE. But that's not the issue. The question is whether there is a theory *T* which *when presented in a natural way* requires open-ended searches to check whether a purported *T*-proof is indeed a proof according to that specification.

[I couldn't think of one when I wrote the first edition of my Gödel book, and I still can't as I work on the second edition. But maybe I'm just being dim/ignorant!]

Answer (score 13):

**Here is another proposal. In this edition, the PS has been completely changed**

Let $T_{ZFC}$ = arithmetical truths that $ZFC$ "knows about", i.e., the set of arithmetic sentences $\phi$ such that $ZFC$ proves $\phi^\omega$, where $\phi^\omega$ is the set-theoretical statement that expresses "$\phi$ holds in the von Neumann interpretation".

$T_{ZFC}$ is an example of a natural r.e. theory whose overt axiomatization is not primitive recursive. Note that $T_{ZFC}$ is much stronger than $PA$, since includes all kinds of statements that are left undecided by $PA$, such as $Con(PA)$, $Con(PA + Con(PA)$, etc.

Moreover, one could argue that this theory is in some sense more natural than $PA$ since it is, implicitly, what mathematicians are really interested in.

Three notes:

1. There are axiomatizations of $T_{ZFC}$ that do not use the Craig trick; see this [FOM posting](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2011-June/015532.html) for more information.
2. As observed by Kreisel, $T_{ZF}$ = $T_{ZFC + GCH}$ (the argument uses Gödel's constructible universe and absoluteness considerations).
3. In light of Harvey Friedman's programme of unearthing the deep role of large cardinals in our knowledge of the finite realm, one can also consider natural variants $T_{ZFC^{+}}$, where $ZFC^{+}$ is the result of augmenting $ZFC$ with appropriate large cardinals.

   **P.S.** Since the original question stipulated that the theory, when naturally presented,  be *recursive*, I offer the following (thanks to Emil Jeřábek and Joel Hamkins for helping to improve this suggestion).

Let $f_G$ be the Goodstein function, i.e., $f_G(m)=n$ iff the length of the Goodstein sequence starting at $m$ is $n$. Note that $f_G$ is recursive, but not primitive recursive. Then perhaps the *equational* theory of $(\Bbb{N}, 0, 1, +, f_G)$  is recursive but not primitive recursive.

**Perhaps even the full theory of $(\Bbb{N}, 0, 1, +, f_G)$ is decidable (i.e., maybe Presburger arithmetic augmented with the Goodstein sequence is a decidable theory)**.

Comment: Excellent example, Ali. Another similar example would just be the theory TA of true arithmetic. This is a commonly considered theory, but of course is not computably or even arithmetically axiomatizable. I would encourage Peter to accept your answer instead of mine...(or wait for even more examples!)

Comment: A lovely example, of course! But what exactly it is an example of? $T_{ZFC}$ is, as you say, a natural r.e. set of sentences of great interest. But it isn't, as presented, a recursively axiomatized theory in the sense in my question -- taking those sentences as the axioms, the property-of-numbering-an-axiom (i.e. of numbering an arithmetical consequence on ZFC) isn't recursive. And the nice reaxiomatizations are primitively recursively axiomatized, no?

So the question remains doesn't it? Are there natural cases of decidable axiomatized theories, where the decision requires unbounded search?


Comment: [Sorry for the seemingly unappreciative terseness, due to the constraints of the comment box!]

Comment: Well, I agree, and it's back to the drawing board for both of us! At the same time, one might object that the question has little mathematics at stake, but rather only the interpretation of what counts as sufficiently "natural". 

Comment: What we gave were examples of theories whose natural axiomatization is c.e. rather than decidable. But you want an analogous example separating decidable from primitive recursive...

Comment: Yep my hope is that there's little mathematics at stake. But I was a bit worried I was missing something interesting ....!

Comment: I think what made Joel and I reach for our r.e.(c.e) examples is that Craig's trick works equally well for r.e. sets and recursive sets of axioms. I will add a PS to offer an example that *might* be of the sort you are looking for.

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t understand the point of the PS. First, the natural axiomatization of $\overline T$ is the same as the natural axiomatization of $T$, which is of very low complexity for the examples you mention. Second, the deductive closure itself is primitive recursive for all your examples. In fact, this could be an interesting variant on Peter’s question: are there any natural examples of decidable deductively closed theories that are not primitive recursive?

Comment: Emil, thanks for your comments. I have completely changed my PS in light of your remarks. I have suggested a possible "dream solution" to the question posed at the end of your comment.

Comment: Ali, isn't the equational theory of your Goodstein example still primitive recursive? (But actually, I not precisely sure exactly what you mean)  But the question of whether $f(m)=n$ is a primitivie recursive relation in both $m$ and $n$, since given $m$ and $n$ I can by a primitive recursive function run the Goodstein construction on $m$ for $n$ steps and see if I get $0$ or not.

Comment: The equational theory of $f_G$ is the same as the equational theory of any other injective unary function: no two syntactically distinct terms are equal. Presumably Ali meant the equational theory of $(\mathbb N,0,S,f_G)$, whose complexity is rather unclear to me: the obvious argument why it shouldn’t be primitive recursive fails as $f_G$ has indeed prim rec graph, but on the other hand, I don’t see how to check equality of more complex terms by a prim rec algorithm (though I’d be inclined to conjecture this is possible).

Comment: I mean, injective unary function with an infinite $f$-chain (or arbitrarily large cycles).

Comment: Also, I rather doubt the first-order theory of $(\mathbb N,0,1,+,f_G)$ could be decidable, since something like $f_G(x+y)+x$ should give a pairing function.

Comment: Emil, the theory of Cantor's pairing function is decidable, so that by itself should not be problematic (the result is due to Cegielski & Richard, 1999).

Comment: In principle, pairing by itself does not imply undecidability, that’s why I only expressed a doubt. However, it does make it very suspect, as naturally occurring theories with pairing are usually undecidable. Notice also that Cantor’s pairing function is undecidable in the presence of addition.

Comment: Emil: we are on the same page; in light of undecidability result you mention, a more hopeful option is to replace + with the successor function in my proposed structure.

Answer (score 10):

Here is one proposal.

Consider the natural theory of the Lindenbaum algebra of an undecidable theory $T$ (and natural examples of these abound). So the theory can refer to objects, which are sentences in the language of $T$, and there is an order relation axiomatized by $\varphi\leq \psi$ whenever $T\vdash\varphi\to\psi$. This is naturally a c.e. axiomatization of the theory, which can therefore be enumerated according a computable procedure, but this process does not seem to provide a primitive recursive axiomatization, except by means of the Craig's trick type reaxiomatization you mention.

Comment: My comment, on reflection, is the same as for Ali Enayat's lovely case. Here too we have an r.e. set of sentences, but not recursively decidable as presented, so not a recursively axiomatized theory in the (I hope non-deviant) sense I was using. No?





Comment: JDH:  Since Lindenbaum algebras define $\forall$ as infinite conjunctions and $\exists$ as infinite disjunctions, what happens to the undecidable theory $T$ in question when such infinite conjunctions and disjunctions are removed and only finite conjunctions and disjunctions remain (bounded quantification)?  If I understand correctly, all terms in the conjunctions  and disjunctions are variable-free.  Does this make this fragment of $T$ 'contentual' ('finitary' in Hilbert's terminology) and is this fragment always  decidable?